# LED wont turn off

Tags: notifications, notification-led

After receiving a message the LED was blinking for notification. After reading the message, the LED shines in dark blue and wont go into previous state, i.e. turn itself off. I tried to restart the phone, remove battery, but nothing helps.

Please, how can I make the LED not to light?

(Galaxy Nexus, 4.0.2)

Comment: Do you have an app called Light FLow installed? That might have an impact - see under ACCESSIBILITY.

Comment: No, it's clean install (no apps at all).

Comment: Try starting it in Safe Mode and see if the LED still acts up, Link - http://www.myvusers.com/forums/samsung-galaxy-nexus/10880-safe-mode-galaxy-nexus-samsung.html

Comment: Thank you for the tip! It all of sudden stopped to shine, when I started to charge the battery. I don't understand. Now, GPS stopped working, hmm..

Comment: reboot after using Safe Mode. Is the light still stuck in normal mode? For GPS issues, use GPS Toolbox and check that you're in sight of satellites.

Comment: I tried both GPS Toolbox and GPS Essentials, and I think the latter worked better. Anyway, thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try starting it in Safe Mode and see if the LED still acts up.. Link - http://www.myvusers.com/forums/samsung-galaxy-nexus/10880-safe-mode-galaxy-nexus-samsung.html