# Why my Nexus 4 keeps blinking the notification LED?

Tags: nexus-4, notification-led

The notification LED in my device is always blinking. There's nothing in the notification area and it keeps blinking. 
Sometimes its a dark blue / violet and sometimes it changes to a white light.

I Don't understand if this is an expected or unexpected behavior. I presume the notification light should be related to the notification area and should stop when it is cleaned.

I read here [LED wont turn off](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21815/led-wont-turn-off) that I should try reseting it. I'll try it if works I post here again.

Comment: Resetting it into Safe Mode and resetting again stopped it.

Comment: For what it is about, you might want to check [What's the default Nexus 4 indicator LED behavior?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37501/16575)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read here LED wont turn off that I should try reseting it. And that's all I needed to fix this problem.
[LED wont turn off](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21815/led-wont-turn-off)

Answer (score 1):

If your device is no more in an area where it can reach GSM network, the notification LED will blink (in white if you installed LightFlow).

Still with LightFlow installed, the dark blie/violet blinking is the notification of a new SMS.